# Metodo para insertar en order en una linkedList javascript

Tags: javascript, lista

estoy luchando con un ejercicio hace rato y siento que la respuesta es bastante mas facil de lo que estoy intentando conseguir.
Muchas gracias de ante mano.

````
LinkedList.prototype.insertMaxToMin = function(value){
  // Tu código aca:
  
}```
````

Comment: *estoy luchando con un ejercicio hace rato* podrias demostrarnos el código que lograste hasta ahora por favor? Tal como esta tu pregunta, pareciera que pides que lo hagamos por ti. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo#4320

Comment: Por lo que vi en el historial de ediciones, esta pregunta tenia código antes. Tal vez sea buena idea (si puedes) revertir tu ultima edicion (si es que el código escrito era tu intento de resolver el ejercicio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo que la lista está siempre ordenada (siempre se usa el mismo método para insertar) y que es una lista encadenada simple (unidireccional, los nodos tienen solo .next y no .previous)

```js
LinkedList.prototype.insertMaxToMin = function(value) {
    let nuevo = new Node(value)

    // Búsqueda de un elemento menor (ya que orden mayor a menor)
    let puntero = this.head  // lo que tú llamas actual o current.
    let previo = null
    while(puntero != null && puntero.value >= value) {
        previo = puntero
        puntero = puntero.next
    }


    // Inserción:
    if (previo == null) {
        nuevo.next = this.head
        this.head = nuevo
    } else {
        nuevo.next = previo.next
        previo.next = nuevo
    }
}
```

### Explicación

Simplemente con un bucle vamos iterando por toda la lista hasta encontrar un nodo que sea menor que el nuevo (ya que se pide orden mayor a menor) o recorrerla entera (toparnos con null). Tenemos un puntero, una variable que recoge la referencia de cada nodo iterado (lo que tú nombraste `current`, también válido).

La gracia está en que también tenemos otra variable para referenciar al anterior nodo iterado (`previo`), esto es necesario porque una vez encontrado un menor, no tenemos forma de obtener su anterior (salvo si los nodos tienen atributo previous además del next).

Una vez recorrida, en previo tendremos un null si la lista estaba vacía o si el nuevo era el mayor de los elementos, por lo que significa que hay que insertar por el principio

```js
...
if (previo == null) {
    nuevo.next = this.head
    this.head = nuevo
}
...
```

Si no es null, tendremos que insertar el elemento entre el actual (puntero, que es lo mismo que previo.next), y el previo.

```js
...
} else {
    nuevo.next = previo.next
    previo.next = nuevo
}
...
```